# getting datagridview last row index

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox

i'm trying to get the last row but the problem is....see my
code

```
Int32 index=dataGridveiw1.Rows.Count; // this is count start 1,2,3,4,5,6

sum3=txt_lotweight.Text-txt_balanceweight.Text;
sum4=datagridview1.Rows[index].Cells["rollweight"].Value-sum3;
```

how to minus gridview last row value to sum3  in this code error
will come rows index not found because rows count start from 1  and
when i subtract rows value to sum3 its start from 0

so how to get last row of gridview

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are not getting last row index, but count that is higher by 1 than last index! That is because array indexing in C# starts from 0.

```
Int32 index = dataGridveiw1.Rows.Count - 1; // this is count start 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

this code will work. But I have doubts about your `sum3` - if your `TextBox` contains integers you should cast it to `int` before subtracting, and `Value` in sum4 is object so casting is required as well.

Comment: i m disabled the Adding property of gridview -1 means second last row

Comment: yup i was cast in my code but -1 is not work because i m disabled the Adding property of gridview -1 means second last row

Comment: @user2491383 It is actually the position of that row in the Row Collection so for the last row you will have to use `Count - 1`

Comment: No, `dataGridveiw1.Rows.Count - 1` means last row. Read [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WorkingWithArrays11232005064036AM/WorkingWithArrays.aspx) tutorial to learn about arrays

Answer (score 3):

Index are basically starts from 0 so if you are using the row count then you have to use it like this to get the last index.

```
Int32 index=dataGridveiw1.Rows.Count - 1 ;
```